# MATLAB: "Index exceeds the number of array elements" error when solving a second-order differential equation

Tags: matlab, ode

I am working on solving a second-order differential equation in MATLAB using finite differences. However, I keep encountering the error message "Index exceeds the number of array elements." I have attempted to adjust the length of the Vb vector in the findiff.m file as suggested in similar questions, but the problem still persists. Can someone please help me identify the root cause of this error and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Here's the relevant part of my code:
File trisys.m:

```
function X = trisys(A, D, C, B)
N = length(B);

% Forward elimination
for k = 2:N
    mult = A(k-1) / D(k-1);
    D(k) = D(k) - mult * C(k-1);
    B(k) = B(k) - mult * B(k-1);
end

% Back substitution
X(N) = B(N) / D(N);
for k = N-1:-1:1
    X(k) = (B(k) - C(k) * X(k+1)) / D(k);
end
end
```

File findiff.m:

```
function F = findiff(p, q, r, a, b, alpha, beta, N)
T = zeros(1, N + 1);
X = zeros(1, N - 1);

Va = zeros(1, N - 2);
Vb = zeros(1, N - 1);
Vc = zeros(1, N - 2);
Vd = zeros(1, N - 1);
h = (b - a) / N;

Vt = linspace(a + h, b - h, N - 1);

Vb = -h^2 * feval(r, Vt);
Vb(1) = Vb(1) + (1 + h / 2 * feval(p, Vt(1))) * alpha;
Vb(N - 1) = Vb(N - 1) + (1 - h / 2 * feval(p, Vt(N - 1))) * beta;

Vd = 2 + h^2 * feval(q, Vt);

Vta = Vt(2:N - 1);
Va = -1 - h / 2 * feval(p, Vta);

X = trisys(Va, Vd, Vc, Vb);

T = [a, Vt, b];
X = [alpha, X, beta];
F = [T' X'];
end
```

File p.m:

```
function result = p(t)
result = 2 * t / (1 + t^2);
end
```

File q.m:

```
function result = q(t)
result = -2 / (1 + t^2);
end
```

File r.m:

```
function result = r(t)
result = 1;
end
```

File main.m:

```
a = 0;
b = 4;
alpha = 1.25;
beta = -0.95;
N = 100;

result = findiff(@p, @q, @r, a, b, alpha, beta, N);

disp(result);
```

Comment: Please highlight specifically which line you are getting this error, which is included in the full error message. Have you tried debugging and stepping through each line? You will probably see somewhere you have an empty array or array with fewer elements than you are indexing - the error message is pretty descriptive

Comment: result =

     1

Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must
not exceed 1.

Error in findiff (line 19)
    Vb(N - 1) = Vb(N - 1) + (1 - h / 2 * feval(p, Vt(N - 1))) * beta;

Error in main (line 9)
result = findiff(@p, @q, @r, a, b, alpha, beta, N);

Comment: The line `Vb = -h^2 * feval(r, Vt);` returns a scalar, so the subsequent request for the value `Vb(N-1)` (where `N=100`) is way out of range, hence the error. Please [debug your code](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to resolve issues like this, one or more of your functions is not doing what you think it is